# java.lang.VerifyError: class com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil$5 overrides final method getRunner.()Lorg/junit/runner/Runner;

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin

While running test cases from IntelliJ - facing this issue. mvn clean install works fine though.

Anyone faced this issue before ?

Comment: Looks like you're using a version of junit that is not compatible with your version of IntelliJ.

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: I got the same exception and for me it helped to temporarily remove the @Ignore annotation

Answer (score 6):

Try to use a JUnit 4 dependency in your maven project.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If has an Annotation @Ignore on Class,this exception will be reported,could comment this annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).